# What is the recommended system requirements for running a Angular site with a WebAPI (MVC 6)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, web-hosting, vps, windows-server-2016

I have just bought a VPS with Windows Server 2016.
The spec is:
2GB RAM,
2 CORE

I think it's not good enough, because when I visit the page, it takes 5+ seconds to load the first page and it does not even call the API. The heaviest page that retrieves data from the API takes 15+ seconds, and that data is cached. And this is only for 1 user.

I have tried to use caching but it doesn't seem to speed up the page. I have changed the heaviest calls from EF to use Dapper.NET instead. It runs fast on my developer machine, but not on the VPS.

Everything is running on same server.
Windows Server 2016,
IIS,
SQL Express Server 2014,
Angular

Any thougts ?

Comment: unfortunately this question is really too broad. there are *many* things that affect performance, and without analyzing your traffic data, browser requests, server logs, etc., it is impossible to know what might be at fault.

Comment: But doesn't 2gb of ram sounds a little small for running windows server, with sql and angular ? This is only for one user, and it takes 15sec to load the page. The page is not available yet so it's only my requests.

Comment: Angularjs is client side, it doesn't care how much memory your server has.  If your server is taking a long time to deliver a page through IIS, then anything coming from that server would be slow.  you seem to have done *some* traffic profiling if you are able to identify the "heaviest calls", but nobody on this site reading this question will be familiar with your configuration enough to help.

Comment: Ok, forget about the front-end part. When I call the API from the browser directly it still takes around 10+ seconds to show the data. I have created my own VPS with same requirements as the one I bought (2GB RAM, 2CORE) WIndows Server 2016 and SQL Server, and I get the data in less than 1s.